# regarding usability in the 'authentication pattern input' UI, such as PIN/pattern

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I'm posting this to ask for opinions regarding usability.

During the authentication process of entering PIN/pattern, there is a service where pressing [Back] during the second entry takes you back to the first entry screen. Would it be better for usability to go to the same page as if [Back] was pressed twice?

For example, let's assume there is a page called [PIN Pattern Registration] where you can move to the [1st Entry of PIN Pattern] page by pressing the [Register] button, and then to the [2nd Entry of PIN Pattern] page for verification.
In this case, if you press [Back] once on the [2nd Entry of PIN Pattern] page, would it be better to go directly to the [PIN Pattern Registration] page? I would like to hear opinions on which option feels more familiar based on your experience with similar services.